# Increase Docker container size from default 10GB on rhel7

Tags: docker, containers, devops

When I launch a container from rhel7.3 image, the default container size is 10GB. I want to increase it to 20GB. I tried the below ways but I had no luck

1) Added "DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS": "--storage-opt dm.basesize=20G" in  /etc/docker/daemon.json file. /etc/docker/daemon.json file is not there by default so I had to add it and tried restarting docker. Restart fails with the below error:

"unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS\n"

2) Added "dm.basesize=20G" parameter while I launch the conatiner

docker run --privileged --storage-opt "dm.basesize=20G" -d IMAGE_ID 
but it fails to launch with error

"docker: Error response from daemon: Unknown option dm.basesize."

Any help on how I can achieve to launch a container with 20GB instead of the default 10GB?
Thanks,
Premchand

Comment: Storage driver is devicemapper

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I changed the storage type to "Overlay" by the following steps

1) Added  {"storage-driver": "overlay"} in /etc/docker/daemon.json file. This file was not there in rhel 7.3 so I added it manually.

2) Restarted docker

My issue of increasing the container volume is resolved as each container get total amount of volume available on the host.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue as you, after a lot of research i found a simple solution:

1. stop the docker service:

   > sudo systemctl stop docker
2. edit your docker service file, located at:

   > /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
3. find the execution line:

   > ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd 
   >   and change it to: 
   > ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G
4. start docker service again:

   > sudo systemctl start docker

all done.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct flag, --storage-opt dm.basesize=some_size, however this is an argument that should be given to dockerd, not docker.

Try reformatting your daemon.json file to contain:

`"storage-opt": [ "dm.basesize=20G" ]`

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. I edited the daemon.json file as suggested by you and I am able to restart the docker service now. How ever when i launch the container, I still see the container size as 10GB

Comment: /dev/dm-3               10G  511M  9.5G   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/6b3903e2634ff651ded83623d649f95ad4441a7bce44d4043fbba17d9a7c6291